# Python's inheritance __init__ which self is this self?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a question about the **init**() and inheritance in Python. The following codes are from thinkbayes:

Suppose we have a parent class Pmf where it has functions such as Set() and Normalize(). Now we want to build another class called Cookie that inherits Pmf class.

```
class Cookie(Pmf):
    def __init__(self, hypos):
        Pmf.__init__(self)
        for hypo in hypos:
            self.Set(hypo, 1)
        self.Normalize()
```

Here my question is that, since this is basically redefining a child class's init() after inheriting the init() from the parent class, we call:

```
Pmf.__init(self)
```

But, after this line,

```
for hypo in hypos:
        self.Set(hypo, 1)
    self.Normalize()
```

Is the "self" in self.Set(hypo, 1) and self.Normalize() the "self" from Pmf class or from the new Cookie class?

I am a little bit confused...
Thank you very much!

Comment: You're making a distinction where there isn't one. The self is the current instance; in this case, it's the instance of Cookie, which has access to all the methods from Pef through inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the `self` in `self.Set(hypo, 1)` and `self.Normalize()` the `self` from `Pmf` class or from the new `Cookie` class?

It's a false dichotomy: there is only one `self`. Its type is the class an instance of which is being created. In your example this is `Cookie`.

Comment: Then could you please help me a bit why we are declaring the Pmf.__init__(self) in the Cookie's init? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote `c = Cookie`, then `self` in both `Cookie.__init__` and `Pmf.__init__` refer to the same instance of `Cookie`. The type of `self` does not change based on which function is called.

The machinery that gets to `__init__` is something like this: `c = Cookie()`  (ignoring a couple of steps) first results in a call to `Cookie.__new__()`, which will return an instance of `Cookie`. That new instance is then passed to `Cookie.__init__`; that instance is what `self` refers to in `Cookie.__init__`. The type of that instance does not change when you make the call `Pmf.__init__(self)`; it's still an instance of `Cookie` being further processed by `Pmf.__init__`.

Comment: Thanks chepner, could you please explain to me the purpose of calling explicitly Pmf.__init__ in Cookie's init?

Comment: Since a `Cookie` is also a `Pmf`, it should be initialized the same as any other instance of `Pmf`. Python doesn't do that implicitly, though; it's up to you to ensure the parent's `__init__` gets called.

Comment: I see, this really cleared my confusion! Thanks a lot chepner!

Answer (score 1):

First you should use the super function:

```
super(Cookie, self).__init__()
```

Second the self always refers to the instance of the object. The fact that you call a method from the self object means that you call the first method of that name found in the inheritance tree travelling upwards. So if the Cookie contains such a method, it will be called, and if it doesn't contain one the one contained in the inherited classes will be used. This is what the super does.

Also, there is a different syntax of super between Python3 and Python2

Comment: `super` comes with its own semantics, and the decision to replace a hard-coded parent-class reference with `super` is not one that should be made lightly or just because you can. There's nothing wrong with using `Pmf` directly, which states that you do *not* support cooperative inheritance.